# What does a angular.mock.$Browser.deferredFns do?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tdd, jasmine, angular-mock

Have you seen a jasmine spec written like this?

```js
describe('#removeAllListeners', function () {

it('should not call after removing listeners for an event', function () {
  socket.on('event', spy);
  socket.removeAllListeners('event');

  mockIoSocket.emit('event');

  expect($browser.deferredFns.length).toBe(0);
});
```